# c++ std::sort unexpected behaviour (Runtime Error)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, c++11, runtime-error, std

can anyone please tell me why std::sort shows this unexpected behaviour.

**This code is giving Runtime Error**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

inline bool compare(string a, string b){
    return a.size() <= b.size();
}

int main(){

        int n = 100;

        string a = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

        vector<string>v;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            v.push_back(a);
        }

        sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);

}
```

**but when i replace `return a.size() <= b.size();` with `return a.size() < b.size();` , it is working completely fine.**

Comment: Please add the error you get when you are using `return a.size() <= b.size();`. You may even get your answer by searching for it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compare function does not meet the requirements for ordering objects using `std::sort`. Change it to

```
inline bool compare(string a, string b){
    return a.size() < b.size(); // Not <= just <
}
```

Why does use of `<=` not work?

All the elements of your vector are strings of equal size. Hence, our sorting works almost identically to sorting a list of numbers.

Given two numbers, `std::sort` has to figure whether one is less than the other, greater than the other, or they are equal.

Given `n1` and `n2`,

1. If `comp(n1, n2)` returns `true`, then `n1` is less than `n2`.
2. If `comp(n1, n2)` returns `false` and `comp(n2, n1)` returns `false`, then `n1` is equal to `n2`.
3. If `comp(n1, n2)` returns `false` and `comp(n2, n1)` returns `true`, then `n1` is greater than `n2`.

If you use `<=` in the compare function, `comp(n1, n2)` returns `true` **and** `comp(n2, n1)` returns `true`. Given that, the sorting algorithm simply cannot sort your objects and goes into an infinite recursion in attempting to do so.

Answer (score 2):

A typical implementation of std::sort uses some variation of quicksort, probably Hoare like partition scheme, which scans an array from the left side as long as values are < pivot, and from the right side as long as values are > pivot. This scheme is relying on a value == pivot to terminate the scans. If a user compare is returning true on equal values, either scan can go beyond the bounds of the array, resulting in a memory access fault.

In a debug build, there may be a check for the user compare, and if it returns true on equal, it could throw an exception instead of getting a memory access fault.